# Search for date returns nothing every time (but date is there, in date format)

Tags: excel, vba, date, search

I have some code which works perfectly for one sheet with date format d-mmm-yy, but the same code will not work on the next sheet which has date format d/mm/yyyy. I have adjusted the code to search for the new format, but still get nothing.
The code here searches the first sheet for relevant dates based on month and year, then searches for that date in another sheet in order to copy cells from that row and bring them back to the original sheet.

Here are both versions:

Version that works:

```
Set rngFnd = wsElog1.Range("A7:A37")

Dim i As Integer
i = 0
    For Each rngRow In rngInput.Rows
        vntInput = rngRow.Cells(1, 1)  ' Dates in Column A

        If IsDate(vntInput) = True Then  ' Ensure Excel sees the value as a date
        
            nYear = year(vntInput)
            nMonth = Month(vntInput)
        
            ' Is the date within target month/year?
            If nYear = nTargetYear And nMonth = nTargetMonth Then
               SrchDt = Format(rngRow.Value, "d-mmm-yy")
           
               Set rngFnd = wsElog1.Range("A7:A37").Find(SrchDt, LookIn:=xlValues)
           
                           
                    Set rngTarget = wsTEff.Range("B" & rngRow.Row)
            
                    wsElog1.Range("GW" & rngFnd.Row).Copy
                    rngTarget.Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsElog1.Range("GX" & rngFnd.Row).Copy
                    rngTarget.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsElog1.Range("HL" & rngFnd.Row).Copy
                    rngTarget.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsElog1.Range("HH" & rngFnd.Row).Copy
                    rngTarget.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsElog1.Range("HK" & rngFnd.Row).Copy
                    rngTarget.Offset(0, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsElog1.Range("GZ" & rngFnd.Row).Copy
                    rngTarget.Offset(0, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsElog1.Range("HO" & rngFnd.Row).Copy
                    rngTarget.Offset(0, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsElog1.Range("HP" & rngFnd.Row).Copy
                    rngTarget.Offset(0, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                
                         
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next rngRow
```

Version that does not work:

```
Dim c As Integer
c = 0
    For Each rngRow In rngInput.Rows
        vntInput = rngRow.Cells(1, 1)  ' Dates in Column A

        If IsDate(vntInput) = True Then  ' Ensure Excel sees the value as a date
        
            nYear = year(vntInput)
            nMonth = Month(vntInput)
        
            ' Is the date within target month/year?
            If nYear = nTargetYear And nMonth = nTargetMonth Then
               SrchDt1 = Format(rngRow.Value, "d/mm/yyyy")

               Set rngFndA = wsRlog.Range("A:A").Find(What:=SrchDt1, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=False)
           
                    Set RngTarget1 = wsTEff.Range("M" & rngRow.Row)
                
                    wsRlog.Range("CP" & rngFndA.Row).Copy
                    RngTarget1.Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsRlog.Range("CM" & rngFndA.Row).Copy
                    RngTarget1.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsRlog.Range("CX" & rngFndA.Row).Copy
                    RngTarget1.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsRlog.Range("CS" & rngFndA.Row).Copy
                    RngTarget1.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsRlog.Range("CU" & rngFndA.Row).Copy
                    RngTarget1.Offset(0, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsRlog.Range("CN" & rngFndA.Row).Copy
                    RngTarget1.Offset(0, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsRlog.Range("CL" & rngFndA.Row).Copy
                    RngTarget1.Offset(0, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wsRlog.Range("CD" & rngFndA.Row).Copy
                    RngTarget1.Offset(0, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                         
                c = c + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next rngRow
```

The range find always returns nothing for RngFndA and I can't figure out why.

SOLVED: I needed to add `Dim SrchDt1 As Date`

Comment: if you set the find format and turn on searchformat= true...does it still not find the date? `Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy"
Set rngFndA = wsRlog.Range("A:A").Find(What:=SrchDt1, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=True)`

Comment: It was throwing an error with the `Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat` telling me it was Null. I have now solved it by adding `Dim SrchDt1 As Date`. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If the range being searched contains actual dates which are consistently-formatted then you could do something like this:

```vb
Dim dt As Date, f As Range, rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B30")

dt = Date + 3 'for example

'use the same date format as used in the search range
Set f = rng.Find(what:=Format(dt, rng.Cells(1).NumberFormat), _
                 lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)

Debug.Print dt, "Found?", Not f Is Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, I just ended up adding 
    `Dim SrchDt1 As Date`
and the problem was solved!